# Get the text till last number

Tags: regex

I wanted to get the string till the last number occurs, can you please guide me how to do that, I have a text as below

Raw text:

```
Jungfrau (40), männlich, sucht... (2005)dfdfdf (123)
```

Output:

```
Jungfrau (40), männlich, sucht... (2005)dfdfdf
```

Regex used:

```
[(][\d+].*
```

Comment: `^.*(?=[(][\d+])` , https://regex101.com/r/gF6vQ0/1

Comment: Thanks Pranav it worked.

Comment: exact regex should be, `^.*(?=\(\d+\))`

Comment: noe that `[\d+]` should match `+` or a `digit` not one or more digit chars

Comment: What is the language/regex flavor/method used? There may be a cleaner way to do it with a capturing group: [`^(.*)\(\d+\)`](https://regex101.com/r/mB6cW1/1).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [positive look ahead assertion here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
^.*(?=\(\d+\))
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/gF6vQ0/2)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Which tool did you use to create the image?

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable feedback the code worked for me.

Comment: @Anoop : glad to help